# How to display the state on the same page when clicked Submit button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a form in react which takes input from the user and stores it in the state. Now, I want to display the state values when the user clicks Submit button in an input field just below the submit button in React.
Im new to react.

Comment: can you show us the code of your component ?

Comment: In the `render` function you would build the output based on the state.  How are you currently rendering your output?  Where are you trying to read from state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make an object (E.g. Credentials) and when someone clicks the button, credential takes the props of the state like this:

**App.js**

```
//import code....
import Form from './Form.js'

//class app code.....

//in the render method:

render() {
    return (
        <Form />
    )
}
```

**Form.js**

```
// import code ....
state = {
   firstName: '', // or what you want
   lastName: '', // or what you want
   email: '', // or what you want
   send: false,
}

//handleChange function
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    })
}

//handleClick function
const handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({send: true})
}
```

**In the Render method**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input name='firstName' onChange={handleChange} />
            <input name='lastName' onChange={handleChange} />
            <input name='email' onChange={handleChange}/>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Send</button>

            {send && 
                <Credentials 
                    firstName={this.state.firstName} 
                    lastName={this.state.lastName} 
                    email={this.state.email} 
                />
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Form // or your file's name
```

**In the Credential.js**

```
//import code...

const Credentials = ({firstName, lastName, email}) => {
    return (
        <h2>firstName is: {firstName}</h2>
        <h4>lastName is: {lastName}</h4>
        <p>email is: {email}</p>
    )
}

export default Credentials
```

Comment: What if I just want the state in a JSON format. Like it appears in the console.log(). I dont want to display each value separately. But just the whole state in the JSON format

Comment: You can use JSON.stringify(), inside credential you put a props (E.g. value={JSON.stringify(this.state)}) and in credential.js you pass props 'value' and in return <p>{value}</p>. This should work. :)

Comment: I have done the same thing but my state is a little different, it has arrays like : state= {
    groups:[
        {type_a:[
            {column1:"",
            column2: "",
            column3: ""}
        ],
        type_b:[
            {column4:"",
            column5:""}
        ]}] }; When I executed the code for this state it gave me an error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in p (at Credentials.js:5)
    in Credentials (at Form.js:91)
    in form (at Form.js:39)

Comment: The error isn't in pass an object in JSON but the error is when you pass value at Credential.js e return in <p>. so watch if there is an error in Credential.js if not can you send me your code?

Comment: In form.js, I have <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>                                <Credentials  value={JSON.stringify(this.state)}/>.                      
 My Credentials.js is : const Credentials = (value) => {
    return (
        <p>{value}</p>
    )
}

export default Credentials

Comment: in Credential you have to put: const Credential = ({value}) /*with a {}*/ => { return ( <p>{value}</p> } export default Credentials. Your error is in ({value}) beacouse you have to put curly brackets

Comment: Oh I get it! Thanks a ton for the help :) Really appreciate it. Just one more thing, in the json format, it is just appending the new array values to the previous ones. What should I do if I want to overwrite the state values ?

Comment: You can do this: this.setState(prevState => ({prevState.groups (or what you want) = what you want but i think you have to rewrite all object with changes.

Comment: OK, I'll try something like this but thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Or you can do similarly like this: setState({this.state.groups[0]type_a[0] = 'test1'}). You know?

Comment: I basically want to output what user fills in the input fields of the form in JSON format on the click of submit button. But right now when I load the application, it displays the original state and when I click submit button it appends to the old state

Comment: you have to put in the state or property=' ' and when click botton the state (or property of state) change from ' ' at what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In React you can use 'useState' to initiate a number or any kind of input. Then set that number when the user clicks on a button.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState();
  let typedNumber = 0;
  
  const btnHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNumber(typedNumber);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={btnHandler}>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => (typedNumber = e.target.value)} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <p>{number}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```